# Pause function execution

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await

I have a function that runs tow async functions that fetch data from the database and when it finish it update a flag to true. 
I have another function that could be run before the tow async functions done fetching the results, what I need to do is to postpone the execution of this function till the flag becomes true. 
I did some searches on google and I found the `asyncawait` that could be used to wait for a result from async function (Promise) but I'm not sure if it could help on my situation. 

some code :

```
self.synchronizeData = function()
{
  var me = this;
  //TODO: add more jobs 
  var jobs = [this.getPostsLastId.bind(this), this.getTrunk.bind(this)];
  Async.parallel(jobs, function(err, result){
    me.lastId = result[0];
    me.trunk = result[1];
    me.ready = true;
  });
}
```

in this function I need to wait for the update flag to be true :

```
self.addPost = function(userId, post){
  //Here I need to check the flag update if it is 
  //true to continue else I need to pause and continue later 
  me.newPosts.push(new Post(++me.lastId, userId, me.data, post));
  //other operations
}
```

Any suggestions ? Thanks in advance

Comment: A "flag" which you "wait" for is called a "promise", and you "wait" for it by saying `promise.then(doSomething)`.

Comment: can you clarify more ?

Comment: A [Promise](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/231/promises#t=201610101039219094425) is an object representing an eventual value, and you use the Promise's methods to call functions on the value once it's available. You can also synchronize and wait for multiple promises at once, or the first of many promises.

Comment: As an example `Promise.all([this.getPostsLastId.bind(this), this.getTrunk.bind(this)]).then(d => console.log(d)); // [LastIdData, TrunkData]`. However you have to use promises throughout. Super easy to convert using the `Promise` constructor. By that i mean if, either dont return promises `.all` wont wait for them to complete. However Promises are not the only solution if copying your code base over is not an option. As you found there are many `async` libraries which solved this issue before we had Promises.